# Running Mist with INFURA

Tags: mist, infura

Is it possible to run the Mist browser with an external ETH client like [INFURA](http://infura.io)?
Yes, I understand this may not be the decentralized paradise we want to get to, but I'd just be happy to run a browser for now w/o having to download the entire blockchain. I understand I'll have to trust INFURA and I'm willing to do that for now.

Comment: For a _faster_ User Experience, use Metamask instead, so you just download a chrome extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=es

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To run Mist using INFURA, you need to start it from the command line

If you are using OSX, this is the command you want

```
 /Applications/Mist.app/Contents/MacOS/Mist --rpc https://ropsten.infura.io
```

To use the main network, replace with `https://mainnet.infura.io`

Comment: Did you succeed using infura on Mist? I've tried on the wallet dapp and it weirdly keeps refreshing the account list.

Comment: for future readers, this should now be
Mist --rpc https://ropsten.infura.io

Comment: is this still working?

Comment: I'm asking because it gives me back an error `2017-05-16 11:19:52.179] [WARN] Sockets/node-ipc - Connection failed, retrying after 1000ms...
`

Answer (score 4):

Also, you may want to try out Metamask, which is a Chrome plugin for connecting to Ethereum, managing your accounts, etc. (Metamask uses INFURA as a backend.)  It's a faster UX since you don't have to download (and possibly sync) Mist.

https://metamask.io/

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metamask/nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn?hl=es

Comment: Thanks, but besides the permissions issue, for some reason MetaMask does not always work on sites, e.g. https://ethereum.github.io/stake-voice/ displays "This Browser does not support Ethereum apps. ". Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: You need to be using Chrome with the MetaMask plugin installed. Are you sure you have both? I only get that error on Stake Voice using non-Chrome browsers.