# Mist RPC to Infura

Tags: mist, infura

I am attempting to connect Mist to ropsten.infura.io. Attempted this: [Running Mist with INFURA](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9928/running-mist-with-infura) but it didn't work.

My command is as follows: mist --rpc https://ropsten.infura.io/ and the error returned is

Sockets/4 - { HTTPError
    at stream.catch.then.data (C:\Program Files\Mist\resources\app.asar\node_modules\got\index.js:123:13)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  message: 'Response code 400 (Bad Request)',
  host: 'ropsten.infura.io',
  hostname: 'ropsten.infura.io',
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/',
  statusCode: 400,
  statusMessage: 'Bad Request' }

Strangely, the following works: mist --rpc https://infuranet.infura.io/

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Hi do you have any solutions on this ? because i'm facing the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is still apparently a problem. It looks like Infuranet works, but all other networks fail. I've also tried by putting my Infura ID in the URL and it still fails. Anyone have any ideas??

Comment: I no longer attempt to do this. Not totally relevant to this question, but I have documented how to deploy a contract in Truffle using Infura here: http://jacksonng.org/Infura-Deploy